# Closest equivalent to subprocess.communicate in Haskell

Tags: haskell, executable, pipe, subprocess, popen

I want to do a popen() / python's subprocess.communicate from Haskell - start a program, give it stdin, and get its stdout/stderr. What's the most direct / Haskellish way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pick either [MissingH](http://software.complete.org/software/projects/show/missingh)'s [`System.Cmd.Utils`](http://software.complete.org/static/missingh/doc//MissingH/System-Cmd-Utils.html) and the standard library's [System.Process](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/process/System-Process.html).  They're easy to use, with both high-level convenience functions (which you simply throw strings at and get strings back, possibly lazily) and low-level plumbing functions (which actually give you handles, like most `popen` functions in other languages/frameworks).

```
import System.Process

main = do
    let cmd = "mail"
        args = ["root@localhost", "-s", "does this act like popen?"]
        input = ["Hello, world!"]
    (rc, out, err) <- readProcessWithExitCode cmd args input
    putStrLn $ "mail exited: " ++ show rc
    mapM_ putStrLn $ map ("out: " ++) $ lines out
    mapM_ putStrLn $ map ("err: " ++) $ lines err
```

Comment: Oops, `input` should be a `String` not a `[String]`.  Well, you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

The other option could be to use [shelly](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly) package